# how to display a comment field with my image whenever I upload an image?

Tags: javascript, html

hope you are all doing well.
I am not so good in JavaScript and I have a question for you.
how to write a function that display a comment field for every picture we upload in our website. I want to display a comment field whenever I upload an image.
here is my code I just need to write a function or something that displays a comment field.

```
     <p>
<input
type="file"
accept="image/*"
name="image"
id="file"
onchange="loadFile(event)"
style="display: none"
multiple
/>
</p>
<button>
<label for="file" style="cursor: pointer">Upload to Album three</label>
</button>
var loadFile = function (event) {
const imagePreview = Array.from(event.target.files);
var output = document.getElementById('output');
imagePreview.forEach((image) => {
const img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = URL.createObjectURL(image);
img.height = 100;
output.appendChild(img);
});
};
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more its unclear what you want to achive

Comment: i want to add a comment box that will automatically show up whenever I upload an image

Answer (score 0):

Your function loadFile work fine you are just missing the output which throw an error of null referencing. therefore you should add div has id output to HTML

```
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: but it is not showing a comment box when i upload a picture